# Pipelines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, channel

From Language guide:
(Prime number finder)

```
fun CoroutineScope.numbersFrom(start: Int) = produce<Int> {
    var x = start
    while (true) send(x++) // infinite stream of integers from start
}

fun CoroutineScope.filter(numbers: ReceiveChannel<Int>, prime: Int) = produce<Int> {
    for (x in numbers) if (x % prime != 0) send(x)
}

    var cur = numbersFrom(2)
    repeat(10) {
    val prime = cur.receive()
    println(prime)
    cur = filter(cur, prime)
    }
    coroutineContext.cancelChildren() // cancel all children to let main finish
```

How is filter taking a paramater which is not a receiveChannel object??? (from 2nd call obv)

Answer (score 0):

Haha it is a receivechannel obj. Trickery.